# Unique conic revolution surface that crosses xz and yz planes in elliptics. (Brazilian Math Olympiad 2008)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, contest-math

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider an ellipse $\varepsilon_1$ defined by the equations $x=0$ and $41y^2+41z^2-80yz+36y+36z-81=0$ and the ellipse $\varepsilon_2$ defined by the equations $y=0$ and $71x^2+41z^2-40xz+18x+36z-81=0$.

Prove that there is a unique conic revolution surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that intersects the plane $x=0$ in $\varepsilon_1$ and the plane $y=0$ in $\varepsilon_2$, and determine the intersection of that surface with the plane $z=0$.

I am not familiarized with conic revolution surfaces, so I tried to prove, in that case, it will have a Cartesian equation at the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+eyz+fxz+gx+hy+iz+j=0$. But, because it isn't true for a general conic revolution surface, I found out this approach hard.

I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: The only coefficient not determined when setting $x=0$ and $y=0$ in the general form is $d.$ $$(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)=(71,41,41,d,-80,-40,18,36,36,-81).$$ So the intersection with $z=0$ is  $$71x^2+41y^2+dxy+18x+36y-81=0.$$ So the question becomes what does it mean to be a surface of revolution? And can you use this to determine $d$?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I agree with you, thanks for your comment. But, firstly we should prove it has a Cartesian equation of this form, right? Or is it obvious in this case? I'm really not used with this type of question.